# How to combine global standard deviation given several sample statistics?

Tags: st.statistics

Is there any approximation formula (best guess?) to calculate global std given multiple set statistics (size, mean, std)?

I have an aggregated statistics from several sets.

```
set, size, mean, std, median
  1,   40,   12,   4,     11
  2,   12,    5,   3,    4.5
  3,   28,    8,  13,      8
```

It is easy to calculate global mean as
$$\mu = \frac{\sum{n_i \cdot \mu_i}}{\sum{n_i}}$$
but unfortunately this won't work for std and median.

Comment: You can find the individual variances and so means of second moments easily enough, then the joint mean of second moments in the way you suggest and then find the overall variance and standard deviation

Answer (score 1):

See e.g. [pooled variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance), [pooled standard deviation](https://www.statisticshowto.com/pooled-standard-deviation/).